# Find the closest value above and under in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array which is consisting of [An elementnumber, x-coordinate, y-coordinate, z-coordinate, radius(polare coordinates), θ(polare coordinates)] 
In this array i need to find the two closest values to a specified number, the one above and the one below. 
This needs to be found in the last columns of the array which holds the θ value.

The range of the values goes from 0 - 1.5707 radian(0 - 90 degrees) and in our case we want to be able to choose the amount of specified numbers we want

```
number=9 
Anglestep = math.pi/2 / number 
Anglerange = np.arange(0,math.pi/2+anglestep,anglestep) #math.pi/2+anglestep so that we get math.pi/2 in   the array
```

For an example i need to find the two values above and under the specified value: "0.17"

```
[...['4549', '4.2158604', '49.4799309', '0.0833661', 49.65920902290997, 0.0849981532744405],
 ['4535', '4.2867651', '49.4913025', '0.0813997', 49.67660795755971, 0.08640089283783374],
 ['4537', '5.6042995', '49.4534569', '0.0811241', 49.7699967073121, 0.11284330708918186],
 ['4538', '6.2840257', '49.4676971', '0.0809942', 49.86523874780516, 0.12635612935285648],
 ['4539', '6.9654546', '49.4909363', '0.0814121', 49.97869879894153, 0.13982362821749783],
 ['4540', '7.6476088', '49.5210190', '0.0813955', 50.10805567128103, 0.1532211602749019],
 ['4541', '8.3298655', '49.5605049', '0.0812513', 50.25564948531672, 0.16651831290560243],
 ['4542', '9.0141211', '49.6065178', '0.0811457', 50.41885547537927, 0.17975113416156624],
 ['4529', '9.3985014', '49.6320610', '0.0812080', 50.51409018950577, 0.18714756393388338],
 ['4531', '10.3884563', '49.7157669', '0.0812043', 50.78954127329902, 0.2059930152826599]..]
```

So what i want as output would in this case be the two values: (0.16651831290560243, 0.17975113416156624)

Comment: Is there guaranteed to be at least one number greater than and at least one number less than the specified number?

Comment: Do you want to find the closest values for each number in `Anglerange`?

Comment: Almost, for every Anglerange we want to find the two closest. The one below and the one above. ?

Comment: @Jako, what is the `dtype` and `shape` of your array?  The one you show is not a numpy array (it mixes floats and strings, but without having a structured dtype).

Answer (score 1):

```
In [30]: np.max(arr[arr < .17])
Out[30]: 0.16651831290560243

In [31]: np.min(arr[arr > .17])
Out[31]: 0.17975113416156624
```

Comment: Cant quite figure out how to use this ?   

Ive tried to use it in a simple way and cant get it to work. 
I assume that arr = "name of my array"   ?

Comment: @JakoBrix that's right and that is the general way you would do it. It may sound pedantic but it avoids ambiguities like this: If you change your question so that you have actual Python code for your data array - e.g. `arr = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])` - and make it have the same datatype and shape as your real data, then you will get more specific answers (e.g. involving the columns you want and so on)!

Comment: If the angles are sorted, as the sample data is, using `np.searchsorted` should be faster: it does a binary search, so it takes logarithmic time, compared to linear time of your naive search.

Answer (score 1):

[@NPE's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19975079/1730674) is correct for a 1d array, but you must first access the `Angle` column of your array.  This depends on the `dtype` (data type) of your array (your array seems to include both strings and floats, which is not allowed for a numpy array).  There are two ways that it might be solved, one by making it all floats, the other by using a structured dtype:

#### All floats

```py
arr = np.array([
    ['4549',  '4.2158604', '49.4799309', '0.0833661', 49.65920902290997, 0.0849981532744405 ],
    ['4535',  '4.2867651', '49.4913025', '0.0813997', 49.67660795755971, 0.08640089283783374],
    ['4537',  '5.6042995', '49.4534569', '0.0811241', 49.7699967073121 , 0.11284330708918186],
    ['4538',  '6.2840257', '49.4676971', '0.0809942', 49.86523874780516, 0.12635612935285648],
    ['4539',  '6.9654546', '49.4909363', '0.0814121', 49.97869879894153, 0.13982362821749783],
    ['4540',  '7.6476088', '49.5210190', '0.0813955', 50.10805567128103, 0.1532211602749019 ],
    ['4541',  '8.3298655', '49.5605049', '0.0812513', 50.25564948531672, 0.16651831290560243],
    ['4542',  '9.0141211', '49.6065178', '0.0811457', 50.41885547537927, 0.17975113416156624],
    ['4529',  '9.3985014', '49.6320610', '0.0812080', 50.51409018950577, 0.18714756393388338],
    ['4531', '10.3884563', '49.7157669', '0.0812043', 50.78954127329902, 0.2059930152826599 ]], dtype=float)
```

Then, to apply [@Jaime's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974945/find-the-closest-value-above-and-under-in-an-array#comment29746324_19975079), use

```py
i = np.searchsorted(arr[:, -1], 0.17)
below = arr[i-1]
above = arr[i]

below
# array([  4.54100000e+03,   8.32986550e+00,   4.95605049e+01,   8.12513000e-02,   5.02556495e+01,   1.66518313e-01])
above
# array([  4.54200000e+03,   9.01412110e+00,   4.96065178e+01,   8.11457000e-02,   5.04188555e+01,   1.79751134e-01])
```

If you want just the angles, then just slice by column as well:

```py
below_ang = arr[i-1, -1]
above_ang = arr[i, -1]

below_ang, above_ang
#(0.166518313, 0.179751134)
```

Note that this assumes that `arr` is sorted by angle.

#### Structured array:

```py
arr = array([ ('4549',  '4.2158604', '49.4799309', '0.0833661', 49.65920902290997, 0.0849981532744405 ),
              ('4535',  '4.2867651', '49.4913025', '0.0813997', 49.67660795755971, 0.08640089283783374),
              ('4537',  '5.6042995', '49.4534569', '0.0811241', 49.7699967073121 , 0.11284330708918186),
              ('4538',  '6.2840257', '49.4676971', '0.0809942', 49.86523874780516, 0.12635612935285648),
              ('4539',  '6.9654546', '49.4909363', '0.0814121', 49.97869879894153, 0.13982362821749783),
              ('4540',  '7.6476088', '49.5210190', '0.0813955', 50.10805567128103, 0.1532211602749019 ),
              ('4541',  '8.3298655', '49.5605049', '0.0812513', 50.25564948531672, 0.16651831290560243),
              ('4542',  '9.0141211', '49.6065178', '0.0811457', 50.41885547537927, 0.17975113416156624),
              ('4529',  '9.3985014', '49.6320610', '0.0812080', 50.51409018950577, 0.18714756393388338),
              ('4531', '10.3884563', '49.7157669', '0.0812043', 50.78954127329902, 0.2059930152826599)], 
             dtype=[('id', 'S4'), ('x', 'S10'), ('y', 'S10'), ('z', 'S9'), ('rad', '<f8'), ('ang', '<f8')])

i = np.searchsorted(arr['ang'], 0.17)
below = arr[i-1]
above = arr[i]

below
# ('4541', '8.3298655', '49.5605049', '0.0812513', 50.25564948531672, 0.16651831290560243)
above
# ('4542', '9.0141211', '49.6065178', '0.0811457', 50.41885547537927, 0.17975113416156624)
```

---

#### Doing it for several values

First, an easier way to set up your range is with `linspace`, which automatically includes the start and end, and is specified by length of array, not step. Instead of:

```py
number=9 
anglestep = math.pi/2 / number 
anglerange = np.arange(0,math.pi/2+anglestep,anglestep) #math.pi/2+anglestep so that we get math.pi/2 in the array
```

Use

```py
number = 9
anglerange = np.linspace(0, math.pi/2, number) # start, end, number
```

Now, `searchsorted` will actually find several points for you just as easily:

```py
locs = np.searchsorted(arr['ang'], anglerange)
belows = arr['ang'][locs-1]
aboves = arr['ang'][locs]
```

For example, I'll set `anglerange = [0.1, 0.17, 0.2]` since the full range isn't in your sample data:

```py
belows
# array([ 0.08640089,  0.16651831,  0.18714756])
aboves
# array([ 0.11284331,  0.17975113,  0.20599302])
```